# Is there any way to obtain Kenward-Roger or Satterthwaite degrees of freedom in glmmTMB or nlme?

Tags: r, mixed-models, inference

As in the title - is there any way to obtain Kenward-Roger or Satterthwaite degrees of freedom in glmmTMB or nlme? glmmTMB is currently the only package, which handles the GLM models **and** allows one to specify the residual covariance structure. Unfortunately, it does not seem to offer the mentioned ways of calculating degrees of freedom in smaller samples. Does anyone have any working code to achieve it?

If not those two, maybe at least the likelihood ratio test? glmmTMB seems only to support the Wald's (through anova).

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [*lavaSearch2* package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lavaSearch2), which gives you Satterthwaite df for models from nlme.

The GitHub-version from the [parameters-package](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/) has a `model_parameters()` function that returns SE, CI, df and p-values for different df-approximation methods, e.g.:

```r
library(nlme)
library(parameters)
data("Orthodont")
model <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)

model_parameters(model)
#> Parameter    | Coefficient |   SE |         95% CI |     t | df |      p
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)  |       17.71 | 0.83 | [16.05, 19.37] | 21.23 | 80 | < .001
#> age          |        0.66 | 0.06 | [ 0.54,  0.78] | 10.72 | 80 | < .001
#> Sex [Female] |       -2.32 | 0.76 | [-3.89, -0.75] | -3.05 | 25 | 0.005

model_parameters(model, df_method = "satterthwaite")
#> Parameter    | Coefficient |   SE |         95% CI |     t |     df |      p
#> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)  |       17.71 | 0.83 | [16.03, 19.38] | 21.23 | 102.58 | < .001
#> age          |        0.66 | 0.06 | [ 0.54,  0.78] | 10.72 |  82.88 | < .001
#> Sex [Female] |       -2.32 | 0.76 | [-3.87, -0.77] | -3.05 |  26.25 | 0.005
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>